# singular fit issue for simple mixed model

Tags: mixed-model

I'm trying to run a simple MLM, but I'm bumping into singular fit warnings:

```r
    y <- Reduce(c,replicate(10, scale(rnorm(700, 0, 1))))
    x <- rep(c("A","B"), each=700, times=10)
    g <- rep(c("g1", "g2", "g3", "g4", "g5", "g6", "g7", "g8", 
              "g9", "g10"), each=7000)
    
    df <- data.frame(y=y, x=x, g=g)
    
    m <- lmer(y ~ x + (1|g), data=df)
    boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I believe the reason for this warning is that there seems to be no variation of the random intercept as `ranef(m)` shows.

I read several answers here in CV suggesting to reduce the complexity of the model, often by removing random slopes. However, this model is already as simple as it can get, and there are no random slopes. I also have over 200 groups in my actual data set so it cannot be that I have too few groups.

What are my options? Should I remove the random intercept entirely?

Comment: This nicely reproducible example is completely balanced, with the same number of observations in each group and the same number of A and B cases in each group. Are your actual data similarly balanced?

Comment: @EdM, yes, my actual data are also balanced

Comment: This example *strongly* violates a basic assumption of `lmer`: namely, that of independence of errors.  You use the same 1400 responses `y` in a dataframe of 70000 observations.  Could you describe the real-world data you are attempting to model in such an unusual fashion?

Comment: @whuber, sorry, yes you're right. I made a typo and already edited the question. The problem however remains even with different `y` values

Comment: Your creation of `y` is so strange that I wonder whether it reflects your intentions.  What would be the problem with `y <- rnorm(70000)` in place of the first line?

Comment: @whuber, my data are actually standardized within each group which is why I used `replicate` although I should have also added `scale()` (edited). Still even with `y <- rnorm(7000)` the problem persists

Comment: @whuber, is there a solution to this problem? I asked another (similar) question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555068/what-to-do-with-a-mixed-model-when-ranef-returns-only-zeros) but it's still unanswered...

Answer (score 0):

Your example model samples fine, if a little slowly (~45 minutes on my laptop), using `rstanarm`. So one solution is to use a Bayesian MLM/LMM:

```
library(rstanarm)
sm <- stan_lmer(y ~ x + (1|g), data=df,
            chains= 4,
            cores = 4)
```

which recovers the expected values:

```
                                   mean   sd   10%   50%   90%
(Intercept)                       0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
xB                                0.0    0.0 -0.1   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g1]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g10]              0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g2]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g3]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g4]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g5]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g6]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g7]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g8]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
b[(Intercept) g:g9]               0.0    0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0 
sigma                             1.0    0.0  1.0   1.0   1.0
```

This is just using the default priors, which you should tune to your specific question. My experience has been that mildly regularizing priors allow these otherwise singular models in `lmer()` to sample adequately.